# How to Learn Flow in CATIA CAA V5 R18 c++

Tags: api, visual-c++, cad, catia, caa

I am new to CAA. I have gone through CAA Documentation. I can find the interface I required for my need but I don't know from where should I query them. In CAA Documentation there is no detailed description of what the Interface is related to. How can I learn the flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the component and related interfaces on the **CAA V5 Object Browser**.

```
Menu > CAAV5 Workspace > CAA V5 Object Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

Query one interface to another will be success if interface implemented on same component. For Example: If interface_1 in implemented with Name Component_1 and interface_2 is implemented with Extension of Component_1. Since both implemented on same component then any query each other.